# Discriminated union discriminated on optional property

Tags: typescript

I've been trying but failing to get this union type to work as I want, is this just not supported?

```
type TestA = { href: string; a: string };
type TestB = { href?: never; b: string };

type TestUnion = TestA | TestB;

const test = (x: TestUnion) => {
  if (x.href) {
    console.log("X is TestA", x.a);
  } else {
    console.log("x should be TestB, but is TestUnion", x.b); // error
  }
};
```

Comment: This is about using a truthy check on a string; if I call `test({href: "", a: ""})` then you end up in the else block.  You should do `if (x.ref !== undefined)` or something similar, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEv84N).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
const testBad = (x: TestUnion) => {
    if (x.href) {
        console.log("X is TestA", x.a.toUpperCase());
    } else {
        console.log("x should be TestB, but is TestUnion", 
          x.b.toUpperCase());
          //~ <-- error, property b does not exist on TestA
    }
};
```

the type of `x.href` starts off as `string | undefined`. Using `(x.href)` as a condition in an `if` statement is performing a [truthiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) check.  And while a truthy `x.href` implies that `x.href` can be narrowed to `string`, a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) `x.href` does *not* imply that `x.href` can be narrowed to `undefined`, because **the empty string `""` is falsy**.

Thus you can get into the `else` block with a `TestA` unintentionally like this:

```
testBad({ href: "", a: "" }); // compiles, but
// RUNTIME ERROR  TypeError: x.b is undefined
```

Oops.

---

If you do an actual check for `undefined` instead of just a truthiness check, things will start working:

```
const test = (x: TestUnion) => {
    if (x.href !== undefined) {
        console.log("X is TestA", x.a.toUpperCase());
    } else {
        console.log("x should be TestB, but is TestUnion",
            x.b.toUpperCase()); // okay
    }
};


test({ href: "", a: "" });
// "X is TestA",  ""
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwCCUC8UDeUAWAnCAZgFxSK4CWAdgOYDcUAhiWVdVAL60BQoksCwAEJpMOfAQD8JShABuEXPQBGzYBRoduPcNDiIAqpXIB7SiL3IoAH36JBWgManEUYAMEMAJiIAUADxILQxNKAEo0AD5MLihYqHICKH8AOjxCcIwYuOynSnhjABsIZILjah8AIgANePhbZAqAGig-ZIZk4GN9MEhcAGEGeAgfUNDubPYoCAKh6Oyc50Li0vKKv1JsYwBXAu8lXXdmpS3gWvrg0yaW5KUOrp6FAaGRsazY9i5OLm+1EDm4tx2Lw+LBpYhQCpXJgQiocV6TBwMYAObBJCAZKC5fJFEplHzojhQAD0RNgOigAFFcLhjLgSNclGctpRPIQqBBvN8uFjToDTuh-IEBBcwpF-rEEklWmCoABCVDoZmsgjszwZN7zLFLXGrGrkOoWJBXVrtTrdXpPYajcZxSbTWaZeZxLU4laVdbwTY7PYHOxHE5nIJGS6NDVO2KtW5mh79QZWsbE0nGADWDBAGo+Xx+AhBYkIJEhzWhkLh3BJEL1BoERuaMK5QA)